# When Irelia uses Q, while dashing between her current location and the enemy's location, is she invulnerable to any spells, abilities or auto attacks?

Tags: league-of-legends

Today I was playing against Irelia and there was one moment when she seemed to be dodging my abilities using q.

Comment: You could add some more info for example: "What hero you using against Irelia and what Skill you use on Irelia."

Answer (score 6):

No she is not invulnerable. It's a simple dash and nothing more. As you don't state which champion you played, its hard to tell why it seemed like that, but I'd guess, that she simply healed around the amount you dealt damage.